# Correcting error in index $i30 for file 4934

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

Every time I'm starting the computer, it starts `chkdsk` and I get this message and the scan doesn't move:

```
Checking file system on C:
the type of the file system is NFTS.
Volume label is OS_Install.

One of your disks need to be checked for consistency. You
may cancel the disk check, but it is strongly recommended
that you continue.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
  155392 file recordes processed.
File verification completed.
  469 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.
  0 EA records processed.
  68 reparse record processed 
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 4934.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 4934
```

I tried starting the computer in safe mode but it just get stuck when trying to load the Windows.

Sometimes Windows loads, give me 2 error about my memory and then blue screens with 2 line of text (that I can't read) and then restarts the computer.

Is there somthing I can do?  Is there a way I can cancel this scan just to make sure my Windows and file are intact?

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hard disk is dying/dead. Disconnect it, get a replacement hard disk, install the OS onto the new one & then move the data from the old one to the new drive

Comment: dude,my dad just fix my computer by using msi recover.. please check your self befor giving people advice. thx

Comment: @samy you should consider adding what was "fixed". We can't read your mind. Also, "fixed" doesn't necessarily mean working hard drive

Comment: he uses the recovery tool that come with the msi computer that you can boot by chossing it. and im pretty sure the hard drive work becuse i can accsess all the infomation on the portion that wasnt deleted in the process. shold i add that as a fixed? becuse im not sure every 1 got this option.

Comment: @samy Please try to be a little nicer with people that are here to help you. Describe what steps you've taken and try to explain **why** you disagree with a proposed solution. -1 on your question.